# how to delete nested properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, nested-object

How to delete nested properties in javascript.

I have example code below which has nested objects and want delete particular nested object on condition I have added condition below.
How to delete the entire object based the condition ?

```
var tenants = [{
    'first': {
        'name': 'first',
        'expired': 1
    },
    'second': []
},{
'first': {
        'name': 'second',
        'expired': 2
    },
    'second': [
        'name': 'third'
    ]
},{
'first': {
        'name': 'third',
        'expired': 3
    },
    'second': [
        'name': 'third'
    ]
},
]
```

```
               tenants.forEach((item)  => {
                        if(item.second.length == 0) {
                            console.log('record found..');                            
                            delete item
                        }   
                        else {
                          Data = item;
                        }                     
               });
```

How can we achieve this get the Expected result as below:

```
var tenants = [{
'first': {
        'name': 'second',
        'expired': 2
    },
    'second': [
        'name': 'third'
    ]
},{
'first': {
        'name': 'third',
        'expired': 3
    },
    'second': [
        'name': 'third'
    ]
},
]
```

Comment: Just filter before you work on it - filter out any objects where second is empty

Comment: you have a syntax error you couldn't save key-value pair inside the `second` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that purpose with your condition

but you have a syntax error in the `second` property you can't save key-value pairs inside the array so I change it to an array of objects instead

```
'second': [ // old one
    'name': 'third'
]

'second': [{ // new one
    'name': 'third'
}]
```

```js
var tenants = [{
  'first': {
    'name': 'first',
    'expired': 1
  },
  'second': []
}, {
  'first': {
    'name': 'second',
    'expired': 2
  },
  'second': [{
    'name': 'third'
  }]
}, {
  'first': {
    'name': 'third',
    'expired': 3
  },
  'second': [{
    'name': 'third'
  }]
}, ];

let filteredTenants = tenants.filter(item => item.second.length)
console.log(filteredTenants)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to correct your array.

```
var tenants = [{
    'first': {
        'name': 'first',
        'expired': 1
    },
    'second': []
},{
'first': {
        'name': 'second',
        'expired': 2
    },
    'second': [
        {'name': 'third'}
    ]
},{
'first': {
        'name': 'third',
        'expired': 3
    },
    'second': [
        {'name': 'third'}
    ]
}
]
```

Then just use array.splice to remove the item from array.

```
tenants.forEach((item,index)  => {
      if(item.second.length == 0) {
           console.log('record found..');                            
           tenants.splice(index,1)
      }   
      else {
         Data = item;
      }                     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `.length` to check the condition your `second` is an array.

```js
var tenants = [{
    'first': {
        'name': 'first',
        'expired': 1
    },
    'second': []
},{
'first': {
        'name': 'second',
        'expired': 2
    },
    'second': [
        'name', 'third'
    ]
},{
'first': {
        'name': 'third',
        'expired': 3
    },
    'second': [
        'name', 'third'
    ]
}
]

var index_to_delete = tenants.findIndex(function(item){
  return item.second.length == 0;
});

tenants.splice(index_to_delete,1);

console.log(tenants);
```

Comment: this wouldn't work in case of multiple items that have empty second `array`  it will get the first item only with empty `array`

Comment: that's right, it did not work in multiple items with empty second array.